# Does the [COVID-19] tag include related behaviour, such as panic-buying?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've added to [covid-19](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) to the question [Are New Yorkers lining up in front of gun shops?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/46098/are-new-yorkers-lining-up-in-front-of-gun-shops)

But that question is not at all about the disease, or the virus that causes the disease. It is about (alleged) panic-buying as a result of fear of the disease and its political effects.

Do you think we need a separate tag? If so what?

Comment: You can keep the same tag, imo. Just update the wiki and excerpt to include "covid pandemic related things".

Answer (score 1):

I for one have tagged my own question on paperwork-check in France with this, since it's clearly related to the pandemic, even if that question of mine was not about the virus/disease in itself.

I suggest that we don't need a new tag for the pandemic-related questions, but we can/should slightly expand the covid-19 tag description to include the pandemic, measures taken to combat it, and possibly even population behavior related to the event(s).

For the record, the current tag description says:

> For questions regarding the coronavirus disease and its causes called COVID-19 by the World Health Organisation (WHO). The WHO say the disease is caused by a virus that is itself called SARS-CoV-2 (severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2) but also known as the 2019 Novel Coronavirus, 2019-nCov, the Wuhan Coronavirus and "the Corona virus".

As a side comment "The WHO say" part sounds a bit too much like tin-foil hat...